# executable file not in path for jupyter notebook in docker container

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#install jupyter
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash demo

#change to new user
USER demo

#set the container working directory to user home folder
WORKDIR /home/demo


#start the jupyter notebook
ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter","notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]`
```

It successfully creating an image. But while running I am getting error like this.

`container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"jupyter\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Any insight how to solve this

Comment: Is it in fact listed in the `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

You are using python3 as a base image, jupyter is not install by default. You should have a look to jupyter image instead: [Jupyter Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook)